# slick 2.0 define generic `find by field` method

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

class RichTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tag, name) {

  case class QueryExt[B](q: Query[RichTable.this.type, B])  {
    def whereEq[C](col: RichTable.this.type => Column[C], c: C) = {
      q.filter { fields =>
        col(fields) === c
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Then it complains

```
[error] /home/jilen/workspace/play-slick/src/main/scala/play/slick/SlickQueryExtension.scala:10: value === is not a member of slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple.Column[C]
[error]         col(fields) === c
[error]                     ^
[error] /home/jilen/workspace/play-slick/src/main/scala/play/slick/SlickQueryExtension.scala:9: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value BooleanColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[scala.slick.lifted.Column[Boolean]]
[error]  and value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Boolean]]]
[error]  match expected type scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
[error]       q.filter { fields =>
[error]                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 6, 2014 1:21:48 AM
```

There have been questions about this, but the answers did not work for 2.0

[How to parametrize Scala Slick queries by WHERE clause conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334634/how-to-parametrize-scala-slick-queries-by-where-clause-conditions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slick doesn't have any information about `C`, so it doesn't know if it can and how it should map it to a database value and if it can use `===` on it. So you get a type error. You will have to use Scala's type system to restrict the type to one for which Slick knows how to map it. You can do this by providing a so-called Context Bound, in this case `:BaseColumnType`.

```
def whereEq[C:BaseColumnType](col: RichTable.this.type => Column[C], c: C) = {
  q.filter { fields =>
    col(fields) === c
  }
}
```

`BaseColumnType` is provided by Slick and using it in this way basically tells the Scala compiler to look for an implicit value of type `BaseColumnType[C]` in scope, where you **call** `whereEq`. Because then it is usually known what `C` will actually be. Slick comes with `BaseColumnType[Int]`, `BaseColumnType[String]`, etc. so at the call site, the Scala compiler can find one when your `C` is really an `Int` or `String` in that particular call and this way pass the info further to Slick.

Same for LiuTiger's question. `abstract class Crud[..., PK:BaseColumnType]` should do the trick, a trait doesn't work with context bounds. When implementing an abstract DAO be prepared to face a lot of challenges and get to the edges of your Scala type system skills and learn quite a bit about type inference order, implicit parameters, etc.

Comment: How can I get ride of `MySQLDriver`, so that I can apply my code to different driver types ？

Comment: You can find loads of examples on the net. One in our examples project: https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBExample.scala

Comment: This seems not work for Option types. How can I define I method works with Option[xxx] type?

Comment: Does using TypedType help? Otherwise you could have a look into OptionMappers used here https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.0.1/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala

Comment: `TypedType` not work, and I really don't know how to use `OptionMappers`